# What is the proper way to exit the whole script?

Tags: python

```
def fu():
    try:
        print('hello')
        fu()
    except:
        print('last hello')
        exit()

fu()
```

So it should raise a recursion error after some time and when it does that I want to exit the whole code.

So what I am trying to get is:

```
hello
hello
...
last hello
```

But it gives something like:

```
hello
hello
...
last hello
last hello
```

So when it raises that error I want to do something and that's all, just quit, no more trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the base Exception type to the except and it will work.

```
def fu():
    try:
        print('hello')
        fu()
    except Exception:
        print('last hello')
        exit()
fu()
```

Comment: Do take a look at @vivekkumar's answer as well. It is best practice to give a specific exception rather than the base exception.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should catch particular 'RecursionError' instead of all exceptions.

```
def fu():
    try:
        print('hello')
        fu()
    except RecursionError as re:
        print('last hello')
        exit()
fu()
```

Comment: Down-voting because there is no explanation given.